# I'm trying to learn how to make a discord bot and the example code it said to run doesn't work, what might be wrong?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm learning how to use the discord.py API and this example code (from here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) does not work. I think it has something to do with the async syntax, but I have no idea what could be wrong with it.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')


client.run('private token that is filled in in the actual code')
```

On line 7, “async def on_ready():”, the error is an invalid syntax on async. I’m using 3.8.3

Comment: Hi Tyler, what is the error message you're receiving ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you provide the full traceback in the question please. Also, what version of python are you on?

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp on line 7 (“async def on_ready():”) an invalid syntax on async. I’m using 3.8.3

Comment: @Diggy. See my reply to samuelmiddendorp

Comment: Do you have any older version of python installed on your machine? It's entirely possible that if you're not running in a virtual environment, then it's running on an older version.

Comment: Are you seeing this error when you run the code or in your editor?

Comment: discord.py doesn't support python 3.7 and up because of the changes in the ways coroutines work. If you want to use 3.7+, use the rewrite.